# AJAX Javascript onchange strange behavior

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-select

My ASP.NET web app includes a JavaScript function that loads 50 images from a database onto a page; the user can navigate to the previous or next pages, or select a particular page from a dropdown list.

Usually, it works as expected, but there is one strange thing happening: after I change the page number with the dropdown, if I then select the Next button, it doesn't add 1 to the page number; instead, it treats the current page number like a string and appends a 1 to it.  (For example, it goes from 2 to 21, and from 10 to 101.)  The previous button works normally, and the next button works if used immediately after hte previous or next buttons - it is only the specific combination of using the dropdown list followed by the next button that has the problem.

Here is the code in question:

```
function getPageOfPhotos(PageNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/PhotoManager.svc/GetSomePhotos",
        data: {"PageNumber": PageNumber},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            ButtonsString = '<table><tr>'

            ButtonsString += '<td><div style="text-align:center"><input type="button" value="Prev Page" '
                           + 'onclick="getPageOfPhotos(' + (PageNumber - 1).toString() + ')"'
                           + (PageNumber < 2 ? ' disabled' : '')
                           + ' /></div></td>';
            ButtonsString += '<td><div style="text-align:center">Go To Page: '
                           + '<select id="GoTo_Page" onchange="getPageOfPhotos(this[this.selectedIndex].value)">';
            for (N = 1; N <= Math.ceil(ThumbnailCount / 50); N++) {
                ButtonsString += '<option value="' + N.toString() + (N == PageNumber ? '" selected' : '" ') + '>' + N.toString() + '</option>';
            }
            ButtonsString += "</select></td>";

            ButtonsString += '<td><div style="text-align:center"><input type="button" value="Next Page" '
                           + 'onclick="getPageOfPhotos(' + (PageNumber + 1).toString() + ')"'
                           + (PageNumber * 50 >= ThumbnailCount ? ' disabled' : '')
                           + ' /></div></td>';

            ButtonsString += '</tr></table>';
            for (var D in data) {
                // Code that uses the photos themselves snipped
            }
        },
        error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
            ButtonsString = "Error getting thumbnails:<br />" + TheError;
        },
        async: false
    });
    $(ButtonsDiv).html(ButtonsString);
}
```

The problem appears to be with:

```
'onclick="getPageOfPhotos(' + (PageNumber + 1).toString() + ')"'
```

PageNumber is supposed to be an integer, but (PageNumber + 1) is being treated as (PageNumber.ToString() + "1").  Changing it to (1 + PageNumber) has the same problem, except that the 1 appears in front (so page 3 jumps to page 13 instead of page 4 or page 31); changing it to (PageNumber * 1 + 1) makes it work correctly.

Is this a known bug, or am I missing something in my code?  Note that it does this with both IE and Firefox.

Comment: Obviousle `PageNumber` is not a number, it's a string. Check the code that calls this and see how it sets the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug that is how string concatenation works.

Convert the string to a number

```
parseInt(PageNumber,10) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
PageNumber = parseInt(PageNumber, 10);
```

at the beginning of the function.

You said that the page number is coming from a drop down. The value of a dropdown is always a string, even if it looks numeric.